# Unlimited arguments for PHP function?

Tags: php, function, arguments

In php how would you create a function that could take an unlimited number of parameters: `myFunc($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4, $p5...);`

My next question is: how would you pass them into another function something like

```
function myFunc($params){
  anotherFunc($params);
}
```

but the `anotherFunc` would receive them as if it was called using `anotherFunc($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4, $p5...)`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php most likely what you want. Define function with no arguments and use this to get what was passed at runtime.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
call_user_func_array('anotherFunc', func_get_args());
```

`func_get_args` returns an array containing all arguments passed to the function it was called from, and `call_user_func_array` calls a given function, passing it an array of arguments.

Comment: +1 func_get_args exists for exactly the situation where you need to pass an arbitrary number of arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Previously you should have used `func_get_args()`, but in a new **php 5.6** ([currently in beta](http://www.php.net/archive/2014.php#id2014-04-11-1)), you can use `... operator` instead of using .

So for example you can write :

```
function myFunc(...$el){
  var_dump($el); 
}
```

and `$el` will have all the elements you will pass.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason why you couldn't use 1 function argument and pass all the info through as an array?

Comment: because this is actually for a function in a loader class, you call `load::library('name', $p1, $p2, $p3, $p4);` it returns a reference to the new class where $p1... is passed to the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for [variable-length argument lists](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) for PHP.

The second part of your question refers to [variable functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php):

> ...if a variable name has parentheses appended to it, PHP will look for a function with the 
>   same name as whatever the variable evaluates to, and will attempt to execute it.